# Who, if anyone, owns the copyright to mugshots in the United States?

Tags: united-states, copyright, public-domain

In the United States, who, if anyone, owns the copyright to [mugshots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mug_shot) (or perhaps *any* "work", if the principles generalize) produced by federal, state, or local employees?

If there is too much variation to cover exhaustively in a single answer, a general description of that variation or a few examples would be great.

Answer (score 14):

The Mugshot was most likely made by a state employee in the course of their work.

**Employees** don't get a copyright for works from their work but their employers do so generally, as that is work for hire. However, the government is different:

- The US government specifically can't have any copyright from works of its employees. They are public domain. [17 USC 101](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/101) & [105](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/17/105)
- State governments are [a little different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_status_of_works_by_subnational_governments_of_the_United_States). Technically they *could* be copyrighted unless they are laws and edicts, but states might disclaim such:

  - Arizona employees make Arizona copyrighted works.
  - California works require public access and are public domain unless the state specifically authorizes a work to be copyrighted.
  - Florida and its employees can't have copyright in government works unless they specifically make a law that carves a work out from this beforehand.
  - **Indiana** employees make technically copyrighted works, but they can't restrict use by obtaining a license or fee in any way under [IC 5-14-3](https://law.justia.com/codes/indiana/2017/title-5/article-14/chapter-3/section-5-14-3-3), making them quasi-public domain.

A public domain image can be done with whatever you want. No strings attached, no rights of rightsholders violated.

**However**, not everything made *on behalf of* the government is made *by* the government: Contractors do have the copyright in the first place, and then can assign it to a government, which does **not** make a work public domain.

Comment: Note also that mugshots are availablue under the public-records laws all or almost all states. I'd argue that such a law effects either a waiver of the exclusive rights of copyright or a license to copy any record it makes available.

Comment: By "state employee" do you mean to include "municipal employee"?  Many if not most police officers are employed by municipalities or counties.  Whether this makes a difference to the analysis probably varies by state.

Comment: None that contractors hired by the US Federal Government produce many works. These are protected by copyright, and in most cases initially owned by the contractor. But many are assigned to the Federal Government.

Comment: @phoog most often, municipalities and counties are not separate entities from the state for such questions but considered subsidiaries.

Comment: @DavidSiegel indeed, but I only concern *government employed* people there, not *government contracted* people.

Comment: @Trish Quite so, but readers may not appreciate the difference. For the matter of that, it is not always made clear whether a work was produced by an employee or a contractor. Many people incorrectly think that n all works paid for by the federal government are public domain.

Comment: Isn't *my likeness* [trademarked] by default? ("A public domain image can be done with whatever you want.") ... "[*you* can do w/e you want with a] public domain image" ???

Comment: @Mazura eh.... no, likeness is not trademarkable at all.

Comment: @Mazura: You have publicity rights, which can be subject to licensing, but are (usually) not trademarks. Publicity rights are rather limited in the US, and mostly apply to things like celebrity endorsements and such, but in theory, you could try to litigate most any commercial use of your image. I'm skeptical you would get very far in the case of e.g. a newspaper publishing a mugshot, however.